# one-way RF signal diode

Tags: rf, diodes, signal

Is there a special diode or band pass filter that will only allow RF signal to go though a wire in one direction like a diode does with electricity?

Comment: Your question needs to more specific. What are the specific properties of the RF signal you are working with? Depending on the signal's properties there are Schottky diodes, PIN diodes, circulators, directional couplers, etc.

Comment: You could try an RF circulator.

Comment: A circulator has the added useful feature that it can split incoming and outgoing signals rather than just blocking one or the other. You can transmit and receive *at the same time on the same channel* without causing much interference between the TX and RX side of things.

Comment: If you are in a (relatively) low power world, you could use PIN diodes designed for the task: http://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/rf-and-wireless-control/rf-diode/rf-pin-diode/antenna-switch/channel.html?channel=ff80808112ab681d0112ab6b07b006e0

Comment: PIN diodes are not non-reciprocal devices, they conduct RF in both directions when on, and block in both directions when off. However, if the signal environment is time dependent, then they can be switched on and off rapidly, though RF switches would be easier to use for this. If it's a case of blocking a transmitter from a receiver, then they can be used to make a signal level dependent limiter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

There are two options for non-reciprocal devices, unfortunately neither is 'simple like a diode', they are an isolator, and a buffer amplifier. Schottky or PIN diodes will not do it, a switch made from them will conduct RF equally well in both directions when on. Attenuators and filters also behave in a reciprocal manner.

The first is a [microwave isolator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolator_(microwave)), though these are usually built with a circulator, with its third port terminated. These work over a narrow range of frequencies, in waveguide only, so you would need adapters to get to and from coaxial cable. The magnet can be big and bulky. They are relatively rare and expensive beasts.

The second is an RF buffer amplifier. These have the drawback of requiring power, but they can be very small, and are broadband, covering a wide range of frequencies. Being an active amplifier, they have a limited maximum power handling, add noise and generate distortion. In a pure reverse signal isolation mode, they tend to be used with an additional attenuator, that cancels their gain, and improves reverse isolation. They are available in a huge range from many manufacturers, most will just drop into a 50ohm system, and are relatively inexpensive.

In the very specific case of protecting a receiver from an adjacent transmitter, a limiter, usually made with PIN diodes, can offer a signal level dependent attenuation function. Note that is still not 'direction dependent' *per se*. For instance, a limiter might be designed to allow no more than +15dBm through it. A +40dBm transmitter will therefore suffer a nominal 25dB attenuation, whereas the receiver signal will not be attenuated.